# Are there any general purpose visual programming "languages"?

Tags: ide, dynamic-typing, static-typing, smalltalk

Lately I've been surveying the programming language landscape and one of the languages I looked at was Pharo, a modern Smalltalk.

Programming using a living system that runs in a virtual machine seems like overkill to me. I also don't like the fact that programs in Smalltalk cannot be fully specified using human-readable text and folder structure. But it made me wonder why we are still programming primarily with text editors and if there is a happy medium between the visual approach and the traditional text based programming approach.

Are there any general purpose visual programming languages that don't involve images and virtual machines and which persist programs in a human readable text format?

I've used Scratch to teach programming to middle schoolers, but I wouldn't call it a general purpose language, and if it persists the program in a human readable format, that isn't at all apparent to the user. I've also  found numerous examples of visual programming tools geared toward IoT but not general purpose programming.

Such a tool would blur the lines between code and no-code programming. It could be a valuable teaching tool. I think it could in some ways be a lot simpler than modern IDEs because it wouldn't have to constantly re-analyse static code to provide things like syntax highlighting, static type checking and syntax errors. You would not be able to reference non-existent variables, invoke non-existent object members, reference non-existent types, forget a closing parenthesis or a closing curly bracket or a closing quote. But unlike Pharo, when you save your program, it would be saved as human readable code which can be edited independently using a more traditional IDE.

Does such a language/tool exist?

Comment: Finding 3rd party resources like specific languages is off-topic for this site, sorry. But let me say this: there were dozens of approaches in the past to create "visual programming languages", but each and every vendor has a different definition of what that could mean, and your post contains barely enough information to understand what you are after. For example, for C#, Java and C++ you find mature visual UI designers, most of them using some human readable text format - but I have no idea if you are not aware of those, or just ruled them out because you have something different in mind.

Comment: @DocBrown Programming practices and methods are specifically listed as a topic for this site, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DocBrown By general purpose visual programming language, I mean one which can specify anything that a general purpose text-based language can. Not just visual elements on a screen, but control structures, operations and procedure calls.

Comment: @DanielArant: our [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is clear on this: *Some questions, even if they appear to fit into one of the above categories, may still be off-topic: ... Product or service recommendations, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs*.

Comment: @DocBrown I wasn't looking for a recommendation. I was asking if such a thing exists.

Comment: All these comments and nobody has bothered to just mention LabView and Scratch?

Comment: @DanielArant: you could try to reword your question - focus more on "why does such a language not exist" or "what makes it so hard to design such a language". But I think you have to edit your question and give a more precise explanation of what such a language should be capable of, and also present some more examples of languages with visual aspects you had found, and telling us why they don't fit into your requirements.

Comment: @pjc50: both were mentioned, Scratch by the OP and LabView in a comment above. The OP ruled Scratch out, and LabView might not be "general purpose" enough for them - I don't know, I think the OP's expectations are currently not given precise enough.

Comment: I think there's a simple thought experiment that's useful here.  Take a simple algorithm such as finding the square-root of a number and try to draw or imagine a way to draw a picture that explains it.  What I think you'll find is that symbols and/or words will be necessary.  On the other hand, if you can do that, I'd truly love to see your solution and perhaps even help you build upon it.

Comment: Square root is easy - draw a square, then emphasize its edge. Alternately, use a compass and a ruler. Any algorithm can be represented by a sufficiently complex flow chart or block diagram. LabVIEW is general purpose - it can generate an executable for various targets (Windows, Mac, Linux, RT).

Comment: @LiorBilia: I would love to see how in Labview you specify an algorithm like Heron's method by visually drawing a square and telling the the system graphically it should estimate the diagonal's length. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There's no effective "visual programming language" of a general purpose kind, in exactly the same way as a pictionary does not replace the need for written English.

It's sometimes useful to have a diagram to supplement text for explanatory purposes, because humans are capable of interpreting a wide array of graphics and such graphics do not need to follow a standard grammar (and can represent things that people are more accustomed to seeing but not describing in words), but once graphics are fully systemised into a mechanically-interpretable "language" and interchangeable with words, it becomes more efficient to just use words.

Comment: I don't know of any visual programming languages that do not involve text. But I'm not necessarily saying that I think it would be effective or better. I have no idea, because the only one I have experience with is Scratch, which is only good for toy projects.